# Overloading addition operator in child class in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

Okay guys imagine situation where I have a parent class and a successfuly overloaded + operator:

```c++
   class parent
   {
      public:
         int a; 
         int b;

         friend parent& operator+(parent& mother, const parent& father)
         {
            //add stuff
         }
   }
   class child : public parent
   {
      public:
         int q;

      friend child& operator+(child& brother, const child& sister)
         {
            output = brother.parent + sister.parent;
            output.q = brother.q + sister.q
         }
   }
```

How can I correctly overload that child addition operator to call the parent, add all the members off the parent class, then add the members of the child class? Can't find any info on this anywhere...

Thanks all

Comment: For starters. binary-add should return by *value*. I'd start by fixing the little broken part of this plan.

Comment: as in "parent operator+(parent& mother, const parent& father)"? I mean thats no problem, I can work that out, I already have the parent class implementation working in my real code anyway but just can't figure out how to do the child

Comment: I need to run so I won't be able to write a proper answer, but [here's an idea](https://godbolt.org/z/W6od4Y)

Comment: Note that you can forego temporary copies by utilizing by-value first-argument operations in Ted's example. E.g. [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/W8sjGd). Worth mentioning, btw, that this nested form of object initialization requires C++17 or later. Your solution won't but the test program certainly does.

Comment: @WhozCraig Re temporary copies: Taking `mother` by-value makes a copy (if an lvalue is supplied) that is moved when returned. Taking `mother` by reference and then copying it locally avoids the move on return because of NRVO so I prefer that way. Re initialization: Yeah, it was just to make an example and the members happened to be public :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know. As I showed it *you* don't make the copy. it's made by the caller. It also supports move-semantics and bring your operator to be exception safe, which was the main reason I refer it that way. To each his own.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah ok, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following helps.

```
class parent{
public:
    int a;
    int b;

    parent& operator+=(const parent& rhs){
        this->a += + rhs.a;
        return *this;
    }

    parent(int aa=0, int bb=0):a{aa},b{bb}{}

    friend parent& operator+(parent& mother, const parent& father){
        mother.a += father.a;
        mother.b += father.b;
        return mother;
    }
};
class child : public parent{
public:
    parent par;
    int q;

    child(int aa=0, int bb=0, int qq=0):par{aa,bb},q{qq}{}

    child& operator+=(const child& rhs){
        this->par += rhs.par;
        this->q += rhs.q;

        this->q += this->par.a;
        this->q += this->par.b;
        return *this;
    }

    friend child& operator+(child& brother, const child& sister)
    {
        brother.par += sister.par;
        brother.q += sister.q;
        // add parent.q and child.a child.b
        brother.q += brother.par.a;
        brother.q += brother.par.b;
        return brother;
    }
};

int main() {
    child c1{1,2,10}, c2{1,3,100}, c3{1,2,10}, c4{1,3,100};

    std::cout << c1.par.a << endl;
    std::cout << c1.par.b << endl;
    std::cout << c1.q << endl;

    c1 = c1+c2;
    std::cout << c1.q << endl;

    c3 += c4;
    std::cout << c3.q << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other problems noted with your code, the answer to your actual question is to either:

- write the base-class call as a qualified function name:  `parent::operator+(left,right);`
- use a reference cast:   `(parent&)left + (const parent&)right;`